# how linker works in some cases?

Tags: c++, linker, dependencies

Currently I am doing research how to reduce link time, I want to find bottleneck, but I don't know in detail whole linking process in some cases, maybe some of you guys can help me with few questions:

1 - suppose I have such dependencies:

mylib1.lib -> myexe.exe <- mylib2.lib

and if I will change mylib1.lib, then mylib1.lib will recompile and relink against myexe.exe, am I right?
what about mylib2.lib will it somehow involved?

2 - now suppose I have such dependencies:

mylib1.lib -> mylib2.lib -> myexe.exe

how compilation and linking will work in that case if I'll change:

2.1 just mylib1.lib

2.2 just mylib2.lib

2.3 just myexe.exe

Comment: For this to be a problem in the first place, I expect those libraries are fairly large. In which case, I'd also expect that there's little to be gained, if anything, from linking them together. It MAY benefit to use a dll instead of linking statically, but it also introduces some more overhead in running the application. (We did some such work for our tests, but that was mainly because we have dozens of test-apps, which when linked statically all get fairly large and take time to copy to the test-system, when dynamically linked, you only need ONE copy of all the library code - less copy time)

Comment: Sure, you can merge on .lib into another .lib to make a bigger wad.  Doesn't have anything to do with the linker, just the library manager.  It isn't very often a good idea, just keeps you disk busy and gives you more opportunity for sword-fight.  YMMV.

Comment: A library is a collection of object files and its common for any linkages between these objects files to not be resolved even if combined into a library. There may be some linkers that can resolve a set of object files into a single object file, but that is a different operation that merging a set of object files into a library.